# comparing javascript dates

Tags: javascript

I have two javascript dates and I want to know if they're the same date. The two dates can be for the same date but have different times: Date1 can be set for 3PM while Date2 can be set for 1AM.

I tried these two options but neither work:

```
// doesn't work when same date but different time
if (Date1.getTime() === Date2.getTime()) 

// gives true when dates are in different months
if (Date1.getUTCDate() === Date2.getUTCDate())
```

What the best way to get true when Date1 and Date2 are the same day, regardless of the actual time within the day?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the day, month and year of the dates and check if they are equal.

```
if (date1.getUTCDate() == date2.getUTCDate() && 
    date1.getUTCMonth() == date2.getUTCMonth() && 
    date1.getUTCFullYear() == date2.getUTCFullYear()) {
 // dates are on the same day
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be getDate() ?? I edit your answer. It seems to be the best way to do it.

Comment: @frenchie: Yes, you are correct. `getDay()` gets the day of the week which wouldn't work. Thanks for fixing it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `toDateString` for your comparison?

Comment: Is there a catch with UTC comparison?

Comment: I've been burned with UTC and Local before.

Answer (score 1):

```
var equalDates = function (a, b) {
  var a_time = a.getTime();
  var b_time = b.getTime();

  var a_days = Math.floor(a_time / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
  var b_days = Math.floor(b_time / (24 * 3600 * 1000));

  return (a_days === b_days);
};
```

You first get the times in miliseconds. Then you round down to days (since 1970-01-01) and compare those.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[`setHours:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)** function on your date object and set `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` and `milliseconds` to zero:

`var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)`

For your specific example, **you could use**:

`if(date1.setHours(0,0,0,0) === date2.setHours(0,0,0,0))`

where `date1` and `date2` are your date objects.

**[`setHours:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours)**

> Sets the hours for a specified date according to local time, and
>   returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC
>   until the time represented by the updated Date instance.

**[EXAMPLE:](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/C6Few/)**

```
var today1 = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0); 
var today2 = new Date().setHours(1,0,0,0); //notice the 1 here

var today3 = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0); 
var today4 = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);

console.log(today1 === today2); //returns false
console.log(today3 === today4); //returns true
```

Comment: @frenchie - The concept is much cleaner than checking each element of the date independently.

Comment: True but look at the number of lines and the gymnastics involved. In truth, it's a matter of personal preference but I prefer less code. I know it works, which is why I upvoted.

Comment: @frenchie - I completely understand. Although the number of lines is simply a "for instance" and can be reduced to merely `if(date1.setHours(0,0,0,0) === date2.setHours(0,0,0,0))` where `date1` and `date2` are your date objects. Either way, I can't argue with personal preference :D

Comment: Yup, programming is part science, part art. Thanks for your answer; I might use the concept of date1.setHours(0,0,0,0) in other parts of my future code. Happy coding!